# Accessing specific data in an object created from a .csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I hope you can help me here, this is probably something simple but its driving me crazy trying to figure it out. So I have used pandas to read data from a csv file into an object "data". If I run "print(data)" I get the first section from the command line below. I want to access the name and the price. "print(data.at[i, "Name"])" works great for the Name column, where I is just a loop counter and represents the rows. However I can't access the price. I thought "print(data.at[i, "price"])" would have worked but it throws the error as you can see from the command line read out below. My full code follows the command line read out.

****Comand Line read out****

```
                                                   Name  SKU Regular price
0     30″ Straight Long Ponytail by Exposed Luxury H...  NaN           NaN

1     30″ Straight Long Ponytail by Exposed Luxury H...  NaN         £6.95

2     30″ Straight Long Ponytail by Exposed Luxury H...  NaN         £6.95

3     30″ Straight Long Ponytail by Exposed Luxury H...  NaN         £6.95

4     30″ Straight Long Ponytail by Exposed Luxury H...  NaN         £6.95

...                                                 ...  ...           ...

2814        Yankee Candle Large Jar - Fairy Floss (1pc)  NaN        £10.50

2815  Yankee Candle Large Jar - Midnight Magnolia (1pc)  NaN        £10.50

2816      Yankee Candle Large Jar - Rose Lemonade (1pc)  NaN        £10.50

2817  Yankee Candle Large Jar - Tropical Fruit Punch...  NaN        £10.50

2818  YSL Touche Eclat Illuminating Pen 2.5ml No.1 (...  NaN        £15.95

[2819 rows x 3 columns]
30″ Straight Long Ponytail by Exposed Luxury Hair (1pc) - 1001 - Light Blonde, 1 Piece
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3629, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'price'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\drwyn\OneDrive\Desktop\Amazon\Scraper\scrape2.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(data.at[i, "price"])
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2275, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2226, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3615, in _get_value
    series = self._get_item_cache(col)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3931, in _get_item_cache
    loc = self.columns.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3631, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'price'
```

****My code****

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

    print(data)

    i = 1
    while i < 6:
      print(data.at[i, "Name"])
      print(data.at[i, "price"])
      i += 1
```

Comment: Is "Regular" a column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your column name. It looks like "Regular price" to me.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks to all for your answers though. :)

Answer (score 2):

A KeyError indicates no column called 'price' exists - maybe a space got in the way?

Try calling `data.columns` to see the exact names of your columns.